How can I make the blue accent more prominent/have more contrast without it looking too bright?
I have a feeling the blue accent hue is not bright enough or doesn't pop up as much as it should, any suggestions to how I could fix that or any hex code recommendations for a new accent on the same hue?


Hi. I notice there's a grammatical error in the text.  The word typeface should be used in the singular when forming a compound noun such as "typeface publisher". If a plural is needed, it's only the most significant word (in your example that would be "publisher") that can take the plural form.

Try #0072FA. You'll get this result:

Download a color contrast analyzer to tune the onscreen readability.
https://www.tpgi.com/color-contrast-checker/
It's free and surely helps to avoid poor foreground-background color combinations, because it's based on solid science of human vision.
The grey texts on the nearly black background should also fulfill the minimum WCAG color contrast requirements. But they already do.
